Redis ft.search lettuce return java object instead of Document<K, V>
Is is possible to return plan java object and not Document<K, V> using lettucemod with Redis Stack?
The API seems to strange, as I understand this:
StatefulRedisModulesConnection<K, V> connection
mean that K is the key of hash and V is the type for values being stored in the hash.
But to be able to issue any query I have to use
StatefulRedisModulesConnection<String, String> connection; ... connection.sync().ftSearch("index_name", buildQuery(params), SearchOptions.<String, String>builder() .limit(0,100) .build()); 
which returns SearchResults<String, String>
Is it possible to have SearchResults<UUID, MyObject> as it is written using standard repository?
Is it even possible to issue any query using ftSearch when K o V are something else that String?
The API looks like this
SearchResults<K, V> ftSearch(K var1, V var2);
and K is the name of the index and V is the query to issue - how come those be something else than String?

Lettucemod's API is a reflection of the RediSearch API, the API returns an array with a number (the number of documents in the result set unlimited), and then an array of key-value pairs (if you aren't using scores), with the key's being the keys of the HASH/JSON, and the value being an array containing the document body, for hashes this is just another array of field-value pairs, for JSON it's usually just one field $ with the JSON string in the value.
Any object mapping would need to be done by your application. FYI, there is also Redi OM Spring which does a lot of the object mapping for you (as well as providing RediSearch in an easily consumable interface)

Thanks for response. I am aware of Redis OM Spring unfortunatelly I would have to switch to Jedis which is not an option now and I had a lot of issues with existing repository configuration, bit I will have a look at source to chwck the mappings.
